# References/Direction on what functional of wealth to optimize for a given goal?

Tags: finance-mathematics, algorithmic-trading, reference-request, modeling, soft-question

I seem to have gotten stuck trying to approach trading strategy development from a financial mathematics(?) perspective.

To start, let:

1. $T \gt 0.$
2. $\mathcal{T}$ be a closed non-empty set of $\mathbb{R}$.
3. $\mathbb{T} = \mathcal{T} \cap [0, T].$
4. $V_t$ be our wealth at time $t \in \mathbb{T}.$

In strategy development/research, I feel like a modest place to start would be to decide what functional of $V_t$ to attempt to optimize as this could determine $\mathcal{T}$ (time scale), our universe of assets, etc.

For example, we may want to optimize, given $V_t \gt 0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{T}$, the expected value of $\text{log}(V_T/V_0)$, however if we believe our model can't fully account for extreme impact rare events and don't want to be open to those potential large risks, we would perhaps pursue building some form of constant proportion portfolio insurance/a structured note-like product where we still attempt to optimize the log return of our wealth as before, but impose that $V_T \geq V_0$ almost surely.

As I'm writing this I'm realizing that this may be falling under utility theory, but am still posting as I am wanting to confirm, am open to references that have asked and answered the same or similar question as this in finance, and am looking for a bit of a check if I'm becoming too tangled in attempted rigor/theory and that if pursuing a bit more practical/applied approach could be beneficial.

Thanks! :)